# UIDatepicker date one day earlier after going below or above min or max date

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have made a custom datePickerView with a done and cancel button.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setupWithMinimumDate:(NSDate *)minimumDate andMaximumDate:(NSDate *)maximumDate andTag:(NSInteger)tag{
    viewToolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor toolbarBackgroundColor];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    datePicker.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    datePicker.minimumDate = minimumDate;
    datePicker.maximumDate = maximumDate;
    tagValue = tag;
}

-(IBAction)doneTapped:(id)sender{
    [self.delegationListener didTapDone:datePicker.date andTag:tagValue];
}

-(IBAction)cancelTapped:(id)sender{
    [self.delegationListener didTapCancel];
}

-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{
    NSLog(@"DATE = %@",sender.date);
    datePicker.date = sender.date;
}
```

You see the Log statement in `datePickerValueChanged`. It gives me back the correct date when I keep inside my minimum and maximum date. But when I scroll above or below my min or max date it always returns me a date which is one day earlier than the date selected.

I know that when I format the date with `NSDateFormatter` it gives me back the correct Date string. But here is the problem, I store the date that I receive from my datePicker on a Realm object.

Now that realm object I sent to a webserver that needs a dateformatting with UTC timezone. So I always sent a date which is one day earlier.

I hope it's a little bit clear, if not please ask !

Comment: It is problem with time zones. All NSDate is the absolute time. On one of your step you incorrect convert NSDate to/from Realm date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i check your code you are `NSLog` of `NSDate` object but `NSDate` log is not sure to return correct `NSDate` because `NSDate` returns current time in GMT time zone so following is the code to do bit calculation of GTM timezone to your local timezone:

```
-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{
    NSTimeZone* GTMTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSTimeZone* SystemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSInteger GTMOffset = [GTMTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sender.date];
    NSInteger Systemoffset = [SystemTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sender.date];
    NSTimeInterval interval = Systemoffset - GTMOffset;

    NSDate* correctDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sender.date];
    NSLog(@"DATE = %@",correctDate);
    datePicker.date = correctDate;
}
```

i was implicated in my project from [here](https://buildingmyworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/get-local-time-from-iphone-local-nsdate/)

Other way is you can convert your `NSDate` in to string with correct dateformate and nslog it that will be show you correct log like following:

```
-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"Todays date is %@",[formatter stringFromDate:sender.date]);

    datePicker.date = sender.date;
}
```

so you can store the date as a string and send it to your backend hope that help to you